# Frontend layout not working after upgrading to Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1

My **`Magento 2.08`** was working fine, but due to new features introduced in Magento 2.1 and curiosity of knowing how upgrade works in Magento 2, I tried to upgrade my Magento to latest stable version of Magento, i.e. **`Magento 2.1`**.

Everything went fine and I found admin panel functionality was working fine after upgrade.

But **frontend is not working** anymore now.

I inspected the problem and found that **`styles-m.css`** and **`styles-l.css`** are showing 404 not found error in page source.

Also below is my system.log file content:

```
[2016-08-10 04:09:15] main.CRITICAL: 
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Srm/cookbook/en_US/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Srm/cookbook/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/source/module/_collapsible_navigation.less' [] []
[2016-08-10 04:09:15] main.CRITICAL: 
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Srm/cookbook/en_US/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Srm/cookbook/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/source/module/_collapsible_navigation.less' [] []
```

I also tried to run **`grunt exec:<themename>`**, but I got below message:

```
A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for
more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you check you compilation mode in admin ?

Comment: I have tried to compile, but no luck.

Comment: Compilation mode must be client side when we deploying. kindly check it.

Comment: How can I check and change compilation mode. Please help. I am new to magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to turn on theme to developer mode if your are not on production mode.

Either by,

> php bin/magento  deploy:mode:set developer

Or, Goto app/etc/env.php

> change 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'' to MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',

After all, follow these steps:

1. Run Command Prompt
2. Navigate to magento 2 installation directory.
3. Run

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

4. Navigate to var directory.
5. Run

> rm -rf var/cache/*
>
> rm -rf var/composer_home/*
>
> rm -rf  var/generation/*
>
> rm -rf var/page_cache/*
>
> rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

6. Run

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Now, it must work fine !!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to regenerate the static content by doing the below steps -

```
1. Delete all folders under pub/static
2. Delete var/cache
3. Delete var/composer_home
4. Delete var/generation
5. Delete var/page_cache
6. Delete var/view_preprocessed
```

Now open your command prompt and go to your root installation of magento 2 and run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`** is not working for magento 2.1.

Comment: I am getting this error: [InvalidArgumentException]                                              
  There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.

Comment: Try to give 777 permission to both pub and var folders and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out compilation mode from here :

```
Store >> Configuration >> Developer >> Frontend Development Workflow >> Workflow type >>
```

Select **"Client side less compilation"**

Remove **Var/** and **pub/static/**

Run Below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check now still issue or not.